# How do I convert .rec file to .avi file using matlab

Tags: matlab, video, matlab-cvst

I am new in matlab and i would like your help. I am working on a project where i use a Hispec camera to record moving objects(The main goal is to measure their velocity). The camera saves the video(actually the sequence of frames) as "autosave1.rec" . I have already created a code but it works with .avi file. Is there any way my code to read the "autosave1.rec" and convert it to "autosave.avi"?
Thanks in advance.

```
filename = 'C:\Users\kornikos\Documents\MATLAB\Autosave4.avi';
hVidReader = vision.VideoFileReader(filename, 'ImageColorSpace',     
'RGB','VideoOutputDataType', 'single');
mov = VideoReader(filename);
VidFrames = read(mov);
nFrames = mov.NumberOfFrames;
```

Here are the first lines of my code. In order to run the code i created the .avi file manually. Hispec camera's menu gives you the opportunity to create an avi file from the rec file that you had recorded.
Now what i am looking for is an algorythm to do this "automatically". Is this feasible?

Comment: You should post what you have done so far.

Comment: What format is the "rec" file?  It may be some sort of raw binary.  You should look at the manual or other information provided by the makers of the camera to see what the specifications are, then use `fread`.

Comment: @nkjt  You were right. We have to use 'fread', but first we have to use 'fseek' and 'fopen'. The output of 'fopen' will be the "fileID" for the other 2 commands. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To read a video file you can use either `VideoReader` or `vision.VideoFileReader`. However, I don't know whether they will be able to read your .rec format.  To write frames into an .avi video file you can use `vision.VideoFileWriter`.

Comment: VideoReader and vision.VideoFileReader don't work. The message that appears when i use them is "Unable to determine the codec required". Now about vision.VideoFileWriter, could you help me with thw syntax? In order to use this function i must have a sequence of frames. How can i extract them from my ".rec" file?